# Extending an interface by changing the object in an object array

Tags: typescript

I have a base interface like:

```
interface base {
    property1: string
    property2: string;
    property3: [{
        something1: string;
        something2: string;
    }];
}
```

I would like to have an interface like:

```
property1: string
property2: string;
property3: [{
    something1: string;
    something2: string;
    something3: number;
}];
property4: number;
```

I was able to achieve the `propert4` using `extend` like:

```
interface extended {
    property4: number
}
```

I also read up on how to extend a property and was doing it like this:

```
type extendedProperty = base['property3'];

interface extendedPropertyInterface extends extendedProperty {
    something3: number;
}
interface extended {
    property3: extendedPropertyInterface;
    property4: number;
}
```

This does not work. I see that `extendedPropert` is of the type

```
[{
    something1: string;
    something2: string;
}];
```

(Notice the Array brackets). How do I get what I want to achieve?

**EDIT:** I cannot change the `base` interface.

Comment: Generics might help here

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this form: `[type]` declares [a tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) and not an array, it should be: `type[]`.

As for what you asked about, you can do this:

```
interface ArrayItem {
    something1: string;
    something2: string;
}

interface Base<T extends ArrayItem = ArrayItem> {
    property1: string
    property2: string;
    property3: T[];
}

interface ExtendedItem extends ArrayItem {
    something3: number;
}

interface Extended extends Base<ExtendedItem> {
    property4: number;
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ArrayItem%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20something1%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20something2%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Base%3CT%20extends%20ArrayItem%20%3D%20ArrayItem%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20property1%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20property2%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20property3%3A%20T%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ExtendedItem%20extends%20ArrayItem%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20something3%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Extended%20extends%20Base%3C%20ExtendedItem%20%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20property4%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D))

---

#### Edit

As you cannot change `base`, this seems to work:

```
interface extended extends base {
    property3: [{
        something1: string;
        something2: string;
        something3: number;
    }];
    property4: number;
}
```

Comment: Ah! I should have said this but I can't change the `Base` interface. Else, I would have done the same. I will make an edit to the question to that effect.

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: You can also reuse base type: `property3: [base['property3'][0] & {something3: number}];`

Comment: @AlekseyL.Awesome. That's exactly what I was looking for. Can you please explain what the `&` is doing here?

Comment: That's [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types)